# vb.net web method to accept json

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

How do I create an asp.net web method that accept :

```
{"LevelNameAddLevel":"Admin","PriviledgeIDAddLevels":"|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|"}
```

as parameters. I did this :

```vb
<WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Function CreateUserLevel(ByVal userLevel As String, ByVal userPrivi As String) As String
    Return "true"
End Function
```

It is not fired. Please help me out.

Comment: if i remember correctly, there is one more parameter u must specify after WebMethod, something like ScriptMethod

Comment: @Dogoku, I have tried that before without any result.

Answer (score 0):

Change the parameters of the method to be an object that is posted that contains the appropriate properties.  Make sure the properties of the newly created vb object matches the names of the json object properties.

Also, make sure the content-type of the request that sends the json is set to "application/json; charset=utf-8"

Refer to this article:  http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/